# Return a file and a string from Controller to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it's possible to send a string to the client and at the same time a file to the client. My purpose it is that if file has been sent to the client, it has also to show up a message of 'file downloaded successfully" like a mix of the following codes that belong to controllers:

```
return File(files, "application/octet-stream", "FNVBA.zip");


vm.OutputMessage = OutputMessages.SuccessDownload;
return RedirectToAction("Crea", "Spedizione", vm);
```

If that's possible only through AJAX, is there some sample to follow? It means I need to send the file to the AJAX request.

Comment: i doubt this is possible 'in general - menaing to be working in all clinets/browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I used for this was to send the file as a byte array in a json object, and include the filename in the object as well.

```
//Snippet from controller:
        try
        { 
            var imageFile = await _imageStore.GetImageFile(gId);
            var imageObject = new RetrievedImageObject();
            imageObject.InitializeFile(imageFile);
            imageObject.Info = await _infoStorageService.GetInfo(gId);
            return  new JsonResult (imageObject);
        }


// Snippet from ImageObject. The filename is derived from the id:
    public void InitializeFile (RetrievedImageFile f)
    {
        DocType = f.DocType;
        Id = f.Id;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            f.FileContentStream.CopyTo(memStream);
            FileContentByteArray = memStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```